# Dropdown doesnt set DataSet value as Selected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, dropdownbox

I have the following dropdown

```
    <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlResident" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="16px">
       <asp:ListItem Value="-999">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="Local">Local</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="Expatriate">Expatriate</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:dropdownlist>
```

And I want to set its `'Selected'` value to the one I received from the Database. But it doesn't set it to those values instead remain at its default Selected option. I do get the result in my datasource but It remains at `--Select--` instead of the other two values(`Local`,`Expatriate`)

This is how I am trying it:

```
ddlResident.SelectedValue = ddlResident.Items.FindByValue(IIf(IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Resident")), 0, ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Resident"))).Value
```

Comment: Did You add `AutoPostback="True"` for `ddl`? I ask, because in Your code missing that... `<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlResident" runat="server" AutoPostback="True" ...` and then use simple under `ddlResident_SelectedIndexChanged(...`, for example `Dim selval = ddlResident.SelectedValue.ToString()` and use it for what You need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Resident")) = False Then
    ddlResident.SelectedValue = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Resident")
Else
    ddlResident.SelectedIndex = 0
End If
```

This will set the value to the Item "Resident" or if this is NULL or empty it will set the ddl to the 1st item (Select)... although based on your code above it will always use the 1st row... which may or may not be what you want... depends on how many records your dataset is returning.